# Represent space and tab in XML tag?

Tags: xml, tags, special-characters, w3c

How can space and tab be represented in an XML tag?

Are there any special characters that can represent them?

Answer (score 73):

I think you could use an actual space or tab directly in XML document, but if you are looking for special characters to represent them so that text processors can't mess them up, then it's:

```
space = &#032;
tab   = &#009;
```

Comment: ...and if you want a non-breaking space you could also use &#160;

Comment: tab   = &#009; doesn't work for me, for Enter key its &#xA;, no numeric

Comment: where can i find a list of these "special characters", and what are they called?

Answer (score 28):

Works for me

```
\n = &#xA;
\r = &#xD;
\t = &#x9;
space = &#x20;
```

Here is an example on how to use them in XML

```
<KeyWord name="hello&#x9;" />
```

Answer (score 22):

<sup>*New, expanded answer to an old, commonly asked question...*</sup>

### Whitespace in *XML Component Names*

**Summary:**  *Whitespace characters are **not** permitted in XML element or attribute names.*

Here are the main Unicode code points related to whitespace:

- `#x0009` CHARACTER TABULATION
- `#x0020` SPACE
- `#x000A` LINE FEED (LF)
- `#x000D` CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
- `#x00A0` NO-BREAK SPACE
- `[#x2002-#x200A]` EN SPACE through HAIR SPACE
- `#x205F` MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
- `#x3000` IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

*None* of these code points are permitted by the [W3C XML BNF for XML names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ```
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

---

### Whitespace in *XML Content* (Not Component Names)

**Summary:**  *Whitespace characters **are**, of course, permitted in XML content.*

All of the above whitespace codepoints are permitted in XML content by the [W3C XML BNF for `Char`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets):

> ```
> Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
> ```

Unicode code points can be inserted as [character references](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references).  Both decimal `&#`decimal`;` and hexadecimal `&#x`hex`;` forms are supported.

- **Hexadecimal**  **Decimal**  **Unicode Name**
- `&#x09;`   or   `&#09;`     [CHARACTER TABULATION](https://codepoints.net/U+0009)
- `&#x0A;`   or   `&#10;`     [LINE FEED (LF)](https://codepoints.net/U+000A)
- `&#x0D;`   or   `&#13;`     [CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0)
- `&#x20;`   or   `&#32;`     [SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+0020)
- `&#xA0;`   or   `&#160;`   [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0)

Answer (score 11):

You cannot have spaces and tabs in the **tag** (i.e., name) of an XML elements, see the specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-STag. Beside alphanumeric characters, colon, underscore, dash and dot characters are allowed in a name, and the first letter cannot be a dash or a dot. Certain unicode characters are also permitted, without actually double-checking, I'd say that these are international letters.

Answer (score 4):

Illegal XML Tag Name Characters can be encoded using Unicode UCS-2. This works very nicely. I am using it to create XML that gets turned into json (JPath is weak compared to XPath). *Notice the handling of spaces, (, ) characters.*
Unicode UCS-2 Code Chart: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html

```
        tag.Name = tag.Name.Replace(" ", "_x0020_");
        tag.Name = tag.Name.Replace("(", "_x0028_");
        tag.Name = tag.Name.Replace(")", "_x0029_");
```

XML:

```
  <Internal_x0020_Chargeback_x0020_ID>{CHARGEBACKCODE}</Internal_x0020_Chargeback_x0020_ID>
  <Bill_x0020_To>{CHARGEBACKCODE}</Bill_x0020_To>
  <Operator_x0020_or_x0020_Directly_x0020_Responsible_x0020_Individual_x0020__x0028_DRI_x0029_>zzz@yyy.gov</Operator_x0020_or_x0020_Directly_x0020_Responsible_x0020_Individual_x0020__x0028_DRI_x0029_>
```

transformed to json via json.net:

```
    "Internal Chargeback ID": "{CHARGEBACKCODE}",
    "Bill To": "{CHARGEBACKCODE}",
    "Operator or Directly Responsible Individual (DRI)": "xxx@yyy.gov",
```

Comment: This answer tracks with what I have seen:  A spreadsheet parsing tool, the flowgear Excel node, translates sheet names and column names into xml tag names.  Spaces are replaced by "_x0020_"

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the issue where multiple and non-space whitespace characters are stripped specifically from **attribute values**, then yes, encoding them as character references such as &#9; will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, to make it work I need to encode hex value of space within CDATA xml element, so that post parsing it adds up just as   in the htm webgae & when viewed in browser just displays a space!. ( all above ideas & answers are useful )

```
<my-xml-element><![CDATA[&#x20;]]></my-xml-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and none of the above answers solved the problem, so I tried something very straight-forward: I just putted in my `strings.xml` `\n\t`

The complete String looks like this `<string name="premium_features_listing_3">- Automatische Aktualisierung der\n\tDatenbank</string>`

Results in:

- Automatische Aktualisierung der

  Datenbank

(with no extra line in between)

Maybe it will help others. Regards