# Read XML file with XmlDocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I tried to read a XML file but I don't receive content of nodes that have just space or tab or new line. Please tell me where I'm wrong.

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <paragraph>
        <sentence>
            <sequence>
                <word>aaa</word>
                <space> </space>
            </sequence>
            <sequence>
                <word>bbb</word>
                <space>    </space>
            </sequence>
            <sequence>
                <word>ccc</word>
                <space>?!</space>
            </sequence>
        </sentence>
    </paragraph>
</root>
```

The code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:/Licenta/files/struct.xml");
XmlNodeList sentences = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/root/paragraph");
foreach (XmlNode sentence in sentences) {
    Console.WriteLine(sentence.InnerText);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output:
aaabbbccc?!

Comment: Have you represented space character as in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514635/represent-space-and-tab-in-xml-tag ?

Comment: Now I tried this solution and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a property on XmlDocument called [`PreserveWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which defaults to `false` causing the behaviour you're observing. You might want to consider switching it to `true` prior to loading your data into the document.