# Not able to unmarshall XML file that contains tabs with JAXB correctly?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<billFile fileName=".dat" hasHeader="false" fieldDelimiter="    "/>
```

The fieldDelimiter contains a tab. When I call Unmarshaller.unmarshal to convert this xml file to an object, the tab gets replaced by a space. I want it to stay as a tab. Here is the java code I have:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;


public class XMLToConfig
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
  {
    String input                  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>    <billFile fileName=\".dat\" hasHeader=\"false\" fieldDelimiter=\" \"/>";
    JAXBContext jaxbContext       = JAXBContext.newInstance(BillFile.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    BillFile bf                 = (BillFile)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(input), "UTF8"));
  }
}
```

Comment: as `input` is assigned to a string literal, use `\t` there

Comment: I got same problem when using \t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Unicode of tab instead of a real tab:

[unicode for tab and sapce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514635/represent-space-and-tab-in-xml-tag)