# Use path as key in FileStorage

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to write a file (json/yaml/xml, the format does not matter) that stores a filepath with a specific `cv::Mat`. As I ended up realizing [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp#L6907%22here%22), the key combination does not allow for a path (/home/user, for example).

```
void
persist_histograms(const QString& filepath, const QHash<QString, Mat>& histograms)
{
    cv::FileStorage storage(filepath.toStdString(), cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

    QHashIterator<QString, Mat> it(histograms);

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        storage << it.key().toStdString() << it.value();
    }
}
```

Is this a real limitation of the `cv::FileStorage`class? Or is there a way of going around it?

The end result should be something like:

```
{
    "/my/path/to/file.png": "<my cv::Mat serialization here>",
    "/my/path/to/another/file.png": "<my cv::Mat serialization here>",
    ...
}
```

#### Observation

The error occurs independently of the format. If I pass a `filepath` that 
ends with either yaml/json/xml the errors are the same:
This is the error if a try adding a letter at the beginning of the key:

This is the error I get when trying the code above:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Incorrect element name /home/user/dtd/images/freckled/freckled_0055.jpg) in operator<<, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 6877
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv 3.2.0/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:6877: error: (-2) Incorrect element name /home/user/dtd/images/freckled/freckled_0055.jpg in function operator<<
```

This is the error I get if I try to add a letter to the beginning of the key.

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Key names may only contain alphanumeric characters [a-zA-Z0-9], '-', '_' and ' ') in icvJSONWrite, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 3896
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have encountered a similar error. If I try to store a matrix in `YAML` format like this

```
std::string fName("/path/to/cameraParams.yml");
cv::FileStorage fs(fName, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "camera matrix" << cameraMatrix;
```

everything works fine. But as soon as I change the file format from `YAML` to `XML`

```
std::string fName("/path/to/cameraParams.xml");
```

I get an error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) /home/shura/software.downloads/libraries/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence_xml.cpp:83: error: (-5:Bad argument) Key name may only contain alphanumeric characters [a-zA-Z0-9], '-' and '_' in function 'writeTag'
```

As I have realized, the reason is that `XML` format does not allow spaces in a tag, while `YAML` does. So for `YAML` the file below is completely valid

```
%YAML:1.0
---
camera matrix: !!opencv-matrix
```

while for `XML` something like this is not allowed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<camera matrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
```

As soon as I replace the space in "camera matrix" by underscore, everything works fine.

```
fs << "camera_matrix" << cameraMatrix;
```

As I have found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514635/represent-space-and-tab-in-xml-tag) `XML` format has some restrictions on symbols you can have in a tag name. In particular, slashes, which you have in names, are not allowed. Dots seem to be allowed in tags, but for some reason OpenCV refuses to work with tags, which contain dots.

Comment: I suppose you could encode the path, e.g. as a sequence of 2-digit hex values.