# XML/SOAP: is TAB a valid character?

Tags: xml, soap

Is a tabulator a valid character for whitespace between elements in XML/SOAP?

```
<a>*TAB*
*TAB*<b>test</b>*TAB*
</a>

*TAB* stands for \t = 0x09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) 0x09 is allowed in XML/SOAP.

Section 2.2 is about characters and as you can see is allowing you to use:

1. tab (0x09),
2. newline (0x0A)
3. CR (0x0D),

from characters before 0x20.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tab characters ([**CHARACTER TABULATION**](https://codepoints.net/U+0009): `&#x09;` or `&#09;`) are allowed in [XML content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) (but [***not* in XML names**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637274/290085)):

> ```
> Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```