# XmlPoke task trims value

Tags: c#, xpath, msbuild, msbuild-task, xmlpoke

Is there a way to use value ending with space as XmlPoke value? When I execute task, value is replaced but without space at the end.

Reproduction:

**test.targets:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="test.xml" DestinationFiles="output.xml"/>
        <XmlPoke Query="/root/element/@attr[.='replaceme']|/root/replaceme" Value="X " XmlInputPath="output.xml"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**test.xml:**

```
<root>
    <element attr="replaceme" />
    <replaceme/>
</root>
```

When I run:

```
MSBuild /v:detailed test.targets
```

I get output.xml without space:

```
<root>
  <element attr="X" />
  <replaceme>X</replaceme>
</root>
```

Is there a way to force XmlPoke to set correct value (with space at the end)?

Comment: Try adding &nbsp; to your xpath.

Comment: That won't work, nbsp is html entity, not xml. I tried with &#160; but that didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I know I've had to use encoded in msbuild from time to time.  New question : I'm confused.  Do you want to update the "attr" or update the element-text (for replaceme)?  Your "I get output.xml" shows updates to both.

Comment: I want to update attribute. Sample just demonstrates that value gets trimmed in both cases.

Comment: @Filip check the answers provided here https://stackoverflow.com/q/514635/5233410

Comment: @nkosi, i tried that already. It doesn't help with my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Value is an MSBuild ["Item"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2017) Usually, items represent file paths and MSBuild treats these in a special (undercover) way.

So, the issue is not related to XML escaping but to MSBuild [item escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-msbuild?view=vs-2017). This is how you can force the space character:

```
<XmlPoke ... Value="X%20" ... />
```

Comment: Good find. I was reading up on one of the supporting inks was wondering if by *undercover* you meant that it works but they make no mention of it? Didn't see it in the table here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Nkosi - what I mean is many msbuild attributes are not really raw strings: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/880d215472e5e2a8d75352f753c8b97b6c2e3a54/src/Utilities/TaskItem.cs#L158